# How to execute map reduce program(ex. wordcount) from HDFS and see the output?

Tags: hadoop

I am new to Hadoop. I have a simple wordcount program in eclipse which takes input files and then shows the output. But I need to execute the same program from **HDFS**. I have already created a JAR file for the wordcount program.
Can any one pls **let me know how to proceed?**

Comment: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/mapred_tutorial.html#Usage

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a cluster set up, even if is a single node cluster. Then you can run your .jar from the hadoop command line:

> [`jar`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/commands_manual.html#jar)
>
> Runs a jar file. Users can bundle their Map Reduce code in a jar
>   file and execute it using this command.
>
> `Usage: hadoop jar <jar> [mainClass] args...`
>
> The streaming jobs are run via this command. Examples can be referred
>   from [Streaming examples](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/streaming.html#More+usage+examples)
>
> Word count example is also run using jar command. It can be referred
>   from [Wordcount example](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/mapred_tutorial.html#Usage)

Answer (score 0):

Initially you need to set up a hadoop cluster as discussed by Remus.

[Single Node SetUp](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/) and [Multi Node SetUp](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/) are two good way to start with.

Once you have the set up done, start hadoop daemons and copy the input files into any hdfs directory.

Prepare the jar of your program.

Run the jar on the terminal using `hadoop jar <you jar name> <your main class> <input path><output directory path>`

(The jar arguments depend on your program)